# How can I make a closed flat base for an object?

Tags: modeling, edges, faces, color

I've made a 3d model of an ancient sculpture with its nearest surrounding. Since I want to publish it on Sketchfab, I need to make a base for it, make it nice and clean, plus reduce it's size to make it more comfortable for further review.

This is how it looked in the begining:
[image]

And this after extruding edges:
[image]

Better but there is still long way to go. This is how I do have some questions. Hope You can help.

I was able to extrude edges of the model along z axis to make a base. But - even I was strictly following the tutorials - I was not able to create single face that would close the model from below. Are there any requirements regarding side faces that need to be fulfilled to get this done? Since the mesh was created in Photoscan, not blender - it does not have straight edges, but it resembles saw or something (unfortunately). Is this a problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In Edit Mode, select all the bottom vertices and then press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> followed by 0 then Enter.

This scales them all to zero on the Z access which will flatten the bottom edge.

Now press F to fill a face for the base.

Comment: Thanks Thistle,

I am new as well. I've edited the question and will stick to rules of the forum.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad I could help. About the single question rule, I think it has to do with the site's database system architecture therefore it makes sense to observe it in future questions.

Comment: I edited out the place where you meantioned that you disagree with @David. This isn't the place to talk about that. If you have issues with what he said, please bring it up on meta, or (I'm not sure if you have enough rep) come join us [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) and we'd be happy to discuss it with you. (just link to this post and explain your belief).

Comment: @TARDIS Maker Hi, I never said that I disagree with David's comment. On the contrary, I said that I agree with him but I could not comment since I do not have enough reputation points, being a new user of the site. I also encouraged the user who posted the original question (I believe the term is OP) to only ask one question per future post. However, since you have removed that section from my answer I cannot prove what I wrote.. I am here only to find help and help other when I can. Thank you

Comment: @TARDIS Maker - regarding No. 3: all of the points in my original answer related to the original question which I believe the OP has edited to conform with site rules. Consequently, as the post stands at the moment the only relevant point in my answer is No. 1 and I have edited my original answer.

Comment: Hello again<

Yes - I edited the original question to follow the rules, so I apologize if it confused anyone. My bad, I am still learning. I can only confirm that Thistle supported David's standpoint

Comment: @Thistle Oh, sorry, I misread that. You actually can read it. There's a link under your answer that says "edited X hours ago" if you click on it, it gives you the edit history. Sorry about the trouble, I'm just really used to people who don't understand how SE works.

Comment: Now I have an actually comment on the content. Keep in mind that creating N-Gons (faces with more than four virticies) can turn out badly. For flat things it tends to be okay, but the more complex the shape is, the more likely it is that it's not going to work well. They can also be hard to work with.

Comment: @TARDIS Maker No trouble, I just don't like it when people twist my words. Thank you for letting me know about your edit. About the N-Gons, Yes, I am aware of the problems you mention - they do not make for good topology - however in this case it was simply about a flat base which was not going to show in the render anyway. Thank you for your comments.